# Как вызвать функцию в JavaScript событии onclick к коде, не в HTML?

Tags: функции, javascript, события

Все просто, есть кнопка, по её нажатию должна вызываться определенная ранее функция 'firstrButtonActive(). Событие onclick прописано в коде javascript не в HTML. Как вызвать функцию таким образом? Я уже всё перепробовал...

```
//Беру кнопку
var buttonFirstTabComments = document.getElementById("buttonFirstTabComments");

//Как я уже пробовал:
buttonFirstTabComments.onclick='firstrButtonActive();'

buttonFirstTabComments.onclick='firstrButtonActive();';

buttonFirstTabComments.onclick=firstrButtonActive();

buttonFirstTabComments.onclick(firstrButtonActive());

buttonFirstTabComments.onclick('firstrButtonActive()');

buttonFirstTabComments.onclick("firstrButtonActive()";);
```

Comment: если использовать ваш синтаксис то:

    buttonFirstTabComments.onclick=firstrButtonActive;

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, теперь всё понял. А то я уже всё перебывал, что можно )) В итоге сделал вызов функции через анонимную функцию так:
   buttonFirstTabComments.onclick=function() {firstrButtonActive();}
Уж очень не хотелось в HTML код вписывать JS и событие onclick (ибо для того их и разделяют) и создавать анонимную функцию с кодом нужной функции тоже не правильно было бы в итоге пришлось вызвать как написал выше. Патом нашёл вообще превосходное решение и выглядит оно так:
buttonFirstTabComments.onclick = firstrButtonActive;
надеюсь кому-нибудь будет полезно ибо эта тема гуглится не очень

Comment: очень хорошо гуглится, надо просто вместо операций с DOM почитать про сам js, тогда вопросов не возникнет подобных. [вот это рекомендую просмотреть](http://es5.javascript.ru/)

*у вас в имени функции ошибка :) first**r**ButtonActive*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
buttonFirstTabComments.onclick = firstrButtonActive;
```

или так:

```
buttonFirstTabComments.addEventListener('click', firstrButtonActive, false);
```

И да, не забудьте назначать обработчики после загрузки DOM страницы, иначе будут ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/comparison

```
element.addEventListener( имя_события, обработчик, фаза)
```

Comment: **поддержка ie>=9** [в ранних ie AttachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility) там-же описан способ приделать эмуляцию AddEventListener универсально

Comment: ie<9 Кому он нужен?

Comment: К сожалению еще многим.

Answer (score -3):

> document.getElementById('buttonFirstTabComments').setAttribute('onclick','firstrButtonActive()');

*Рекомендация от меня, а меня лучше не слушать* **//**И пожалуйста, на используйте такие длинные имена. Лучше but1Com. Если таких несколько, то для понятности при объявлении первого напишите //1 - 1st tab

Кстати, мини лекция. У объекта из тега таким образом (.%attribute%) можно пробраться только для style. Остальное [только так](http://samsonov.bn.by/lib/php/function.dom-domelement-setattribute.html)(см. "Смотрите также" снизу)

Comment: можно пробраться только для style?

.setAttribute('onclick','firstrButtonActive()'); ???

cool story bro

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что obj.style работает, остальное нет (при obj.onclick="ura()" он ничего не меняет у obj. А .setAttribute универсален

Comment: ужос какой. одна из худших рекомендаций что я видел.